# Unit Testing Against Exceptions

Tags: unit-testing, objective-c, error-handling, swift

I am writing a Swift library.  I'm writing unit tests for that library.

I am afraid that some of the code that I am testing will possibly throw exceptions.  In Swift, we can handle errors, but we can not handle exceptions.  Exceptions are considered programmer errors which should be caught and fixed before release.  They shouldn't be handled at run time.

In order to automate the process of catching these exceptions, I wanted to write some Objective-C code which would allow me to catch these exceptions that my Swift code could potentially throw (because someone refactored and broke it).

So, I came up with this solution:

```objc
@implementation ObjCTry

+ (NSException * _Nullable)executeBlock:(__attribute__((noescape)) void (^ _Nonnull)(void))block {
    @try {
        block();
        return nil;
    } 
    @catch (NSException *exception) {
        return exception;
    }
}

@end
```

I'm not particularly thrilled about the name, nor do I think calling it from Swift is necessarily the prettiest.

So I wrapped that in this Swift function:

```swift
func BCTAssertNoException(@noescape closure: () -> Void) {
    let exception = ObjCTry.executeBlock(closure)
    XCTAssertNil(exception)
}
```

And that cleaned up the usage in Swift a little bit.

Example usage:

> ```
> func testExample() {
>     BCTAssertNoException {
>         let object = NSObject()
>         object.performSelector(Selector("fooNotExistSelector"))
>     }
> }
> ```

---

As a note, I can't seem to get this to catch Swift fatal errors, but my actual use-case concern is unrecognized selector, and it does catch that.

Comment: This works well, except for server-side Swift where you can't make use of Objective-C code. :(.

Comment: Maybe you could take a look at Nimble for unit testing:
https://github.com/Quick/Nimble#exceptions